# why do we have two messages WM_KEYUP and WM_KEYDOWN

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc, keyboard

I am just started the MFC programming and haven not done any UI design or programming before. I was wondering why there are two messages WM_KEYUP and WM_KEYDOWN generated by windows when every key which is getting pressed is sured to be getting released assuming a working keyboard.

I think only one message WM_KEYPRESSED or something else should suffice but is there a reason why windows generate separate messages

Thanks

Comment: Say you want to walk forward by pressing W in a game and holding it  down your solution of WM_KEYPRESSED wouldn't work. It needs WM_KEYDOWN to start the walking forward "state" and WM_KEYUP to stop it.

Comment: Don't forget that keystoke messages also have a repeat counter, so while you hold a key down, you will get repeated keystroke messages with an increasing counter each time. So you can move to the next step on each repeat message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that you can implement modifier keys, like shift and control.
For most keys, you can ignore the `WM_KEYUP`, but if the key in
question is supposed to modify any key pressed while it is held
down, you need both.

Answer (score 1):

I used to ask same question back than but the answer is simple. These are just two separate events that windows gives you opportunity to respond too. There is nothing special about KEY_DOWN or KEY_UP, both are just events. It typically make more sense to handle KEY_DOWN for most needs but sure there are many uses for`WM_KEYUP`. There are many many more messages that windows generate that typically programmer don't handle.